# How to bubble up a custom error when using DELEGATECALL?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, revert-opcode, solidity-0.8.x, custom-errors

Solidity v0.8.4 introduced [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/):

```
error Unauthorized();
```

Say I have contract A which delegate calls to contract B. The latter reverts with the custom error defined above. How can I bubble that error up in contract A?

Comment: What deos "bubble that error" mean ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. This is from the link you posted: "The error data by default bubbles up through the chain of external calls, which means that a contract may forward an error not defined in any of the contracts it calls directly. Furthermore, any contract can fake any error by returning data that matches an error signature, even if the error is not defined anywhere."

Comment: Hey @LauriPeltonen, that's a good point. I updated the question title to be more specific. The question is particularly about the case when using DELEGATECALL.

Comment: @Itération122442 contract A would revert with the same custom error as contract B, not a different error, and not a generic reason-less revert.

Comment: The [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) mention that try/catch should caught an exception. Did you try using them?

Comment: Not yet, will do. Thanks for the tip @Ismael.

Comment: @Ismael Did you notice that the docs also say that try/catch doesn't apply to `delegatecall`? Errors only "bubble up" to be catchable for non sub-calls.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out this function I modified from the openzepplin's Address.sol.

```
function _delegatecall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
    (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.delegatecall(data);
    if (!success) {
        if (returndata.length == 0) revert();
        assembly {
            revert(add(32, returndata), mload(returndata))
        }
    }
    return returndata;
}
```

`returndata` is a dynamic-sized byte array. If the delegate call fails, `returndata` would be the error object raised by the failed call. Say I have contract A which delegate calls to contract B. The latter reverts with the custom error `GonnaMakeIt(uint256 data)`. Then, the `returndata` would be:

```
0xbf42f2660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000539
  +------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
  selector                       uint256 data
```

Then, we make use of Yul's `revert(p, s)` to revert with the custom error in contract A. `p` refers to the pointer of where the error byte array starts, `s` refers to the how long the byte array is.

Since `returndata` is a dynamic-sized byte array, the first 32 bit of the pointer stores the size of it, which we `mload(returndata)` to retrieve it. And similarly, `add(32, returndata)` would be the pointer to where the byte array starts. Altogther, it forms the line `revert(add(32, returndata), mload(returndata))`, which reverts the error you get from contract B.

Comment: From where can you discover such an exact solution? What reference do you use?

Comment: Check openzepplin [Address.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/c239e1af8d1a1296577108dd6989a17b57434f8e/contracts/utils/Address.sol#L201) and solidity documentation on [Yul](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/yul.html).

Comment: It works, but if you're using custom errors and trying to get the error on a hardhat test then you have a problem, at least until https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1618 gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a call or a delegatecall doesn't revert while calling a function that reverts.

> (bool success, bytes memory result) = to.call/delegatecall{value,gas,etc}(data).

The success variable will determine if the call was successful `true` or unsuccessful `false`.
So if you call:

> ```
> error Unauthorized(string reason);
>
>
> function withdraw() public {
>    revert Unauthorized("No Funds"); // or revert("No Funds") 
> }
> ```

The call won't revert but the `success` bool will be false.
So to revert and return the error you need extra code.

> ```
> function delegate(address to,bytes memory data) public  {
>      (bool success, bytes memory result) = to.delegatecall(data);
>    
>        if (!success) {
>        if (result.length < 68) revert();
>        assembly {
>            result := add(result, 0x04)
>         }
>        revert(abi.decode(result, (string)));
>        }
> }
> ```

So if you execute a delegatecall/call on the withdraw function you'll get (Remix):

> ```
> revert
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Reason provided by the contract: "No Funds".
> ```

This works on the new type of error and the old one too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I don't think it covers my question. I am not interested in getting the "No Funds" string. Custom errors are not an updated version of revert reasons - they are a different animal altogether. Thus I am interested in bubbling up the name of the custom error itself: "Unauthorized".

Comment: Sorry i don't know about that. Hope my answer will help someone else.