# Is there any way to bubble up custom errors without using low-level assembly?

Tags: solidity, assembly, custom-errors, revert, try-catch

Is there any way to bubble up custom errors without using low-level assembly?

Say you have a custom error defined like this:

```
contract For {
    error Unauthorized();
    
    function reverWithError() {
        revert Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

And in another contract `Bar`, you make a call to `Foo`, like this:

```
contract Bar {
    function func(Foo foo) {
        try foo.revertWithError {}
        catch (bytes memory err) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to bubble up the `Unauthorized` error in the `catch` arm above, without using low-level assembly?

I checked the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/control-structures.html#try-catch) but I couldn't find any guidance on this.

Side note: I have previously asked a [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/109457/24693), and the answer I received there was great, but it used low-level assembly.

Comment: Lol i had no idea about the existence of comment section. so "May I ask why you don't want to use assembly? Is a key way to manipulate data (I do not think is possible without assembly)"

Comment: I just prefer to use non-assembly when the gas difference is negligible. I think that higher level Solidity is more readable and less error-prone.